# Accessing the variable outside the function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am developing a skill for Amazon Alexa in lambda using Node.js.

I've declared the variable globally, and initialised in function and accessing it outside the function. But I'm getting undefined error. Please help.

```js
var res;
async function classSection(handlerInput){


  standard = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.Class.value;
  section = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.Section.value;

  var speechOutput = `Starting attendance for class ${standard}, section ${section}. <break time = "3s"/> 
  I will call the Names of the students, please say Present or Absent to Mark the attendance. <break time = "1s"/> Lets Start.  `;

    //getting the list of students from database
    con.connect(function(err){
        if(!err) {
            console.log("Database is connected");    
        } else {
            console.log("Error connecting database");    
        }
    });

    const sql = `SELECT StudentDetailID,StudentName FROM attendance_system.student_detail where student_detail.Class = ${standard} 
    and student_detail.Section = '${section}';`;

    console.log(sql);
     con.query(sql, function (err, result, fields) {
        con.end();

        if (!err){
            console.log(result);
            console.log("Table Data : "+result[1].StudentName);

            res = result[1].StudentName;
            console.log("Speech : "+ speechOutput + res);
            //Here in res I get the name of the student.   

        }
        else
    console.log('Error while performing Query.');
        });

    console.log(res);
//here I get undefined error.
 return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechOutput + res)
            .reprompt()
            .withSimpleCard('Attendance System',`Class : ${standard} \n Section : ${section}`)
            .getResponse();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Possbile duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687275/undefined-value-after-returning-an-array-of-values-from-a-mysql-query-in-a-diffe/55688488#55688488

Answer (score 0):

I am looking questions related to similar problem very often in this forum. Either the documentation on Async-Await is not sufficient or there is some misunderstanding about the usage of Async-Await with callback functions.

There are 2 problems in your case.

1. con.query is Asynchronous function. So, by the time the your callback function is called, 'console.log(res);' would have already executed and hence nothing is defined in res variable.
2. You cannot use callback with Aysnc-Await syntax. You have to promisify your callback and use it in Async function to get the expected result.

   [Here is the example for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687275/undefined-value-after-returning-an-array-of-values-from-a-mysql-query-in-a-diffe/55688488#55688488)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a possible solution was use the promisify method, because of this execution is asynchronise

```
const promisify = require('util').promisify

async function classSection(handlerInput){

    try {
        standard = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.Class.value;
        section = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.Section.value;

        var speechOutput = `Starting attendance for class ${standard}, section ${section}. <break time = "3s"/>
        I will call the Names of the students, please say Present or Absent to Mark the attendance. <break time = "1s"/> Lets Start.  `;

        //getting the list of students from database
        await promisify(con.connect)();

        const sql = `SELECT StudentDetailID,StudentName FROM attendance_system.student_detail where student_detail.Class = ${standard}
        and student_detail.Section = '${section}';`;

        console.log(sql);

        const result = await promisify(con.query)(sql)

        console.log(result);
        console.log("Table Data : "+result[1].StudentName);

        const res = result[1].StudentName;
        console.log("Speech : "+ speechOutput + res);
        //Here in res I get the name of the student.

        console.log(res);

        //here I get undefined error.
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
                    .speak(speechOutput + res)
                    .reprompt()
                    .withSimpleCard('Attendance System',`Class : ${standard} \n Section : ${section}`)
                    .getResponse();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Some Error was throwed', err);
        throw err;
    } finally {
        if (con.isConnect()) con.end() // i dont know if isConnect exists
    }
}
```